# Firebase error 2001. How can I fix it?

Tags: ios, cordova, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am developing a cordova app for ios and i am using the cordova plugin named "cordova-plugin-firebase" on npm. I have both certificates on fcm console.

When I start my application, in xcode's console it says "connected to fcm" and when I send a notification I get:

```
Unable to connect to FCM. Error Domain=com.google.fcm Code=2001 "(null)"
```

It appears only when I send a notification from firebase console.

Comment: Did you check previous questions about the same error? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-cloud-messaging%5D+2001

Comment: Yes.. only the 1st result is similar to my problem but the question has no useful answers

Answer (score 0):

did you try to using different FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType?

you can found more info about this issue in the link:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseinstanceid/api/reference/Enums/FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType